# Check if your JSON validator in python output True or False

Tags: python, json, file, testing, yaml

Hi im using the python lib "from jsonschema import validate"
When I using it with it seems it's working I guess but, how can I get a confirm in my CLI when I'm executing this script.

Python file

```
from jsonschema import validate
import yaml

yaml_schema = open("test.yaml", "r")
json_schema = open("test.json", "r")


validate(yaml.full_load(json_schema.read()), yaml.full_load(yaml_schema.read())) # passes
```

test.yaml file

```
type: object
properties:
  testing:
    type: array
    items:
      enum:
        - this
        - is
        - a
        - test
```

test.json

```
{
    "testing": ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
}
```

how can I get a confirm from the terminal, has someone a method for me

Comment: Have you tried writing `print(True)` at the end of your script?

Comment: Please improve your question. Are you trying to validate a JSON against a given JSON scheme?

Comment: "If no exception is raised by validate(), the instance is valid." (https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).  So not seeing an error message is your confirmation.  If you want more than that, you'd have to just add a print statement afterward.